# County/ZIP Combination Layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I'm creating a territory map using QGIS that is based on both county and ZIP code. I need a shapefile for all county/ZIP combinations in Arizona (would look like a ZIP code shapefile except that all ZIP codes that are in more than one county would be split by county lines into multiple polygons).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Something like an intersection between both shapefiles and dissolving for each county/ZIP combination?

Answer (score 1):

*vector>geoprocessing_tools>union*, then you'l have both zip and county fields in your *united* shapefile